# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY. Entity includes ForeignKey Id property

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm doing one to many relationship database with Entity Framework with an `Id` property.

I have two model classes:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

        public int TeamRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamRefId")]
    public virtual TeamModel TeamModel { get; set; }
}

public class TeamModel
{
    public TeamModel()
    {
        TeamMembers = new List<PersonModel>();
        this.Tournaments = new HashSet<TournamentModel>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonModel> TeamMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TournamentModel> Tournaments { get; set; }

    public virtual MatchUpEntryModel MatchupEntry { get; set; }
    public virtual MatchUpModel Matchup { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm trying to create a new `Person` entity, I get this error:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.PersonModel_dbo.TeamModel_TeamRefId". The conflict occurred in database "Tournament2", table "dbo.TeamModel", column 'TeamId'.

Comment: A Team with the TeamRefId you used doesn't exist in the TeamModel table. Since you added a FKey to PersonModel referencing that table/field, that is now a requirement to create a Person.

Comment: @JacobH So, should i do somehow default value for teamrefid?

Comment: A default value would mean that every player belongs to the same team right? Is that true for your data?

Comment: @JacobH i accually don't know how to do it :(

Comment: The foreign key is checking to make sure you don't put any bogus values into the `TeamRefId` field for your Person. You either have to create the Team to which you want to assign the Person first, or you have to allow `Person.TeamRefId` to be null (this can be updated later, like after the Team is created).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making Foreign Key in Person Model nullable should solve your problem 
note that created person will have No Team until you Modify it later after your create Team

```
 public class PersonModel
 {
  [Key]
  public int PersonId { get; set; }

public string NickName { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }

public int? TeamRefId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("TeamRefId")]
public virtual TeamModel TeamModel { get; set; }
}
```